# Error connecting MS-Access database from PHP (DSN-less) Windows

Tags: odbc, dsn

I has reinstalled Windows 7 (64-bit) including PHP and Apache Server (Using WAMP SERVER). I had a code running ok in the previous instalation (I do not know which version of php and apache did) but now is not working.

When I run it appears a warning without information and it does not conect: Warning: odbc_connect ()

I have more than three days trying to solve the problem but I can not found the solution, any ideas?

The current versions are:
Windows 7 64bit
PHP 5.4.3
Apache 2.4.2

The code is:

```
$db = 'D:\database.mdb';
$dsn = "Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};  charset=UTF-8;Dbq=$db";
$conn = odbc_connect( $dsn, '', '' );
```

Thank you!
Javier.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the problem solution but I has uninstalled WAMP Server and I has installed XAMP Server and it works again! –  jakama just now   edit